# How to run maven generated jar on CLI

Tags: java, maven, command-line-interface

I'm trying to get a maven managed project to run on the command line.

I have a set of dependencies in the pom.xml which are subsequently downloaded and installed in the ~/.m2/repository/. I've included the necessary config in my pom to add the classpath to the jar manifest.

Now the problem is i'm attempting to run the jar thus: java -jar project-SNAPSHOT.jar.

Java can't find the downloaded dependencies (i'm assuming because they are listed without paths in the manifest?) , but i'm not sure how best to get this running.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Options 1:
The jar created does not have the dependent jar files. So, you need to tell java the class-path where all the dependent jars are

```
    java -cp /lcoation/of/dependency1.jar:/location/of/dependency2.jar:/location/of/dependency3.jar -jar project-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Option 2:
The easier and much better solution is to use `AppAssembler` plugin. What it does it packages your jar in a directory structure that contains

1. dependent jars
2. the created jar
3. shell/windows scripts to execute it

have a look here http://www.mojohaus.org/appassembler/appassembler-maven-plugin/

Option 3:
If you do not want all the baggage and just wanted to have one `jar-with-dependency`
You may want to refer here [How can I create an executable JAR with dependencies using Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven)

This will contain all the dependent jars within it.

---

**Edit 1:** For Option 1, [Brad M](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1399659/brad-m) mentioned that you can get a list of all your project's deps using the [dependency plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/build-classpath-mojo.html). `dependency:build-classpath`

Comment: Awesome - that's exactly what I needed. Are there any caveats with packaging everything up like this or is it all ok. Memory usage etc?

Comment: No nothing. Its very simple stuffs, same as 1. making jar, 2. copying dependents in a repo folder, 3. writting a shell script that looks something like this `java -jar ../myapp.jar Mainclass -cp ../repo/*.jar`

Comment: re Option 1, get a list of all your project's deps using the [dependency plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/build-classpath-mojo.html).
`dependency:build-classpath`

Answer (score 7):

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.vineetmanohar.module.Main" -Dexec.classpathScope=runtime
```

You can find more examples here: [3 ways to run Java main from Maven](http://www.vineetmanohar.com/2009/11/3-ways-to-run-java-main-from-maven/).

Comment: Doesn't work for me with maven 3.0.4
`[ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase ".mainClass=my.Main"`